# Fallback for SVG injected with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm using [iconic](http://useiconic.com), and it uses JS to inject the icon I want in the DOM.

I would like to have a proper fallback setup for when the JS fails to load. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: This is a very broad question, and invites opinionated answers. Please edit the question to be more specific about your challenge. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you @Mikkel, now I see that this question was very poorly posed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Iconic, but with the Iconfu [SVGInject](https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject) (which is similar) there is a built-in fallback if Javascript is not enabled. Also, there is an `onFail` hook that you can use to handle cases when Javascript is enabled, but the injection fails.